# Map nested data by row r

Tags: r, nested, apply, purrr

I have data that look like this (thanks once again dput!):

```
dat <- structure(list(vars = c("var_1", "var_2"), data = list(structure(list(
  time = 1:10, value = c(1:10
  )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
  )), structure(list(time = 1:10, value = c(11:20
  )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
  ))), mu = c(1, 2), stdev = c(1,2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-2L))
```

I am trying to mutate an extra column which maps a function over each row. e.g calculate dnorm for each element of the nested variable in `dat$data[[1]]$value` using `dat$mu[1]` and `dat$stdev[1]` and the go on to do the same for row two.

The column I would like to mutate is a tibble [10 x 1] for each row containing this as the output:

```
dnorm(dat$data[[1]]$value, mean = dat$mu[1], sd = dat$stdev[1])
dnorm(dat$data[[2]]$value, mean = dat$mu[2], sd = dat$stdev[2])
```

Things I have tried that don't work but might be close?:

```
# This alternates between mean and stdev for each element of each nested variable
dat_1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(z = map(data, ~ dnorm(.x$value, mean = dat$mu, sd = dat$stdev)))
# apply by row has structure issues
dat_2 <- dat %>% 
  apply(MARGIN = 1, function(x){
  mutate(x, z = map(data, ~ dnorm(.x$value, mean = dat$mu, sd = dat$stdev)))
    })
```

a basic map function like this `dat_3 <- dat %>%   mutate(sigma = map(data, ~ sum(.x$value)))` works fine without referencing other values in the df. This is early days for me using nested data and map in this way - been looking at the documentation for all the map functions to try solve this but no luck yet! If that's clear as mud I can try clarify - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a parallel map:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

expected_out1 <- dnorm(dat$data[[1]]$value, mean = dat$mu[1], sd = dat$stdev[1])
expected_out2 <- dnorm(dat$data[[2]]$value, mean = dat$mu[2], sd = dat$stdev[2])

out <- 
  dat %>% 
  mutate(z = pmap(list(map(data, "value"), mu, stdev), dnorm))

all.equal(out$z, list(expected_out1, expected_out2))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I was struggling to understand pmap, makes much more sense now!